# How can I convince my employer to let me bring my own chair to work?

Tags: work-environment, health, england

I work as a Graphic Designer for a company, so spend a lot of time sitting down at a desk. For the past two years, I have suffered from disabling migraines and a 24/7 tension headache. My physiotherapist has concluded that my chair is causing the problem. The chair really kills my back, which causes my neck to stiffen up, which then leads to my headache.

I have asked HR numerous times over the past 6 months if I can have my workstation assessed, but she has declined. I have asked them if they can buy me a new chair, but they think there's nothing wrong with my chair as it's ok for everyone else.

I tried a medical chair and noticed a huge improvement. I have since bought one and it's now at my home. I have asked HR about bringing in my own chair, but she asked me to speak to my line manager. The line manager was reluctant to allow this, and said he would speak to the owners. I haven't heard from him for about a week now.

The chair that can help me end the pain is at home, but my employer doesn't seem to happy to let me use it at work. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: In general, getting work to buy you an ergo chair or letting you use one you bought yourself seems like a great idea. But you've spoken to HR and your manager already with no success, so there's something company-specific happening here. I don't see how this site can help you with that.

Comment: Can you please tag with location?

Comment: so weird, why would they not want you to use a better char

Comment: @atxgis I know it really puzzles me

Comment: Just to let you know that your request is legitimate and not rare. The pain has a tendency to increase exponentially by the time and persist longer. At our office, we are 12 employees, me and a co-worker has bring our chair from home.

Comment: Can you get an accommodation by working like half-day at home with your ideal setup while management is evaluating the proposition?

Comment: @SebastienDErrico unfortunately the company doesn't like people working from home

Answer (score 9):

You probably have medical reason to use that chair, so you have valid reasons to bring it to work.

What you could do is to **get some letter or Medical note** explaining your condition and the need you have to use a special chair (probably with your physio). Then **bring the chair to work anyways**. It's about your health and wellbeing, they can't restrict you from such things (at least not a decent company).

Not being able to use such chair at work could cause you even more health problems. You could try working from home but that would be avoiding the problem.

As a last note, remember that **HR is NOT your friend.** In future situations you could try probing this with your boss if possible before attempting going to HR, which could only slow the process down or even be unreasonable like here.

**Edit:** For the sake of reference, here is a [link](http://www.hse.gov.uk/pUbns/priced/hsg57.pdf) to a *"Guidance on how to ensure the safety and suitability of workplace seating"* (thanks to Motosubatsu for the link), as well as the [Disability Discrimination Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1995/50/contents) for the UK. Also, the [Equality Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/contents) which seems a more recent legal document that is also supportive here (thanks to Daveoc64 for pointing it out).

Comment: Good answer.. having worked at a company that mucked me around on this very issue for about a year I probably should have paid that red flag more heed as they were the antithesis of a decent company!

Comment: The note is huge. In the US, the Americans with Disabilities Act **requires** companies(over a certain size, I think 50 employees) to make what are called "reasonable accommodations" and a chair that alleviates your problem is most certainly one. Theoretically, it also prevents them from terminating you or disciplining you for having to do so.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you! 
When I have obtained my medical notes, is it worth me showing it to someone particular or just having them handy for when I'm quizzed on bringing my own chair in?

Comment: There is similar legislation in the UK as well under the *Disability Discrimination Act*

Comment: @Aggle I would show it *if/when* they ask you about that. No need to be confrontational here by waving the note in their faces. If they don't say a thing then even better (probably they thought it twice now and saw they were being unreasonbale)

Comment: @DarkCygnus thanks for the advice, i'll give it a go. I'll wait a week or so for them to forget about it, then just bring it in. I can access the office at night also, so they won't see me bringing it in and possibly make a fuss

Comment: @Aggle Personally, I would not wait a week. It's one more week of damaging your back and headaches. The night idea is a good one :) that could probably work great.

Comment: HR is not your friend, but, if you have a provable medical need for a different chair, I'd think turning to HR might lead to the fastest resolution, as delaying the process might lead to company getting sued. The manager may not take the request particularly seriously or provide the fastest resolution, although they do have a direct interest in keeping you happy (which HR does not), and might thus just agree to letting you bring your own chair (if able).

Comment: @Dukeling OP indicated that going through HR was already tried unsuccessfully (and unreasonably). Hopefully manager is more reasonable and knowledgeable of situations like this. Still, it was suggested that OP just give it a go as there are medical and legal reasons that back it up.

Comment: My manager is the more likely source of success, as opposed to HR but waiting on my manager to do anything could be months and a lot of nagging on my part.

Comment: @Aggle added some links that you may find useful :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus appreciate it, you've been a massive help!

Comment: @motosubatsu The Disability Discrimination Act was repealed in 2010. The Equality Act is the current law that would be relevant here

Comment: @Daveoc64 thanks for the feedback. Would you mind sharing a link so I can include it in the answer, so OP and other users benefit from it?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I think that this is the current piece of legislation - https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/contents